# Using MPI_Wtime() in Openmpi

Tags: time, runtime, mpi

I am trying to measure the runtime of an mpi programm. I am running it with different number of processes to compare the runtime later.

After calling `MPI_Init()`  I call and save the value of `MPI_WTime()` in a value.
Before calling `MPI_Finalize()` I call `MPI_WTime` and save its value some in another variable.
After `MPI_Finalize` I subtract the two values of `MPI_WTime()`.

My program looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
     double start, end;
     MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
     start = MPI_Wtime();
     //Do something.......
     end = MPI_Wtime();
     MPI_Finalize();
     if(rank==0){
        printf("Runtime=%d\n", end-start);
     }
}
```

This works. The problem is just the results I get. Unfortunately I get no seconds. Running the Program with one process returns a number like this : `41291472` and running the program with 64 processes returns `1978567624`.
These values are no seconds! How can I convert them to seconds?

Comment: In `printf()`, `"%d"` doesn't mean "double".  The mnemonic "decimal" may help.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
printf("Runtime=%f\n", end-start);
```

Your `start` and `end` variables are doubles, so the result of `end - start` is also a double value. You need to use to correct format specifier in `printf`, which is `%f` for floating point values. Using `d` will interpret the result as an integer and you'll only get garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Mort's answer is correct.  I only wanted to add that MPI_Wtime does not return an integer count of elapsed seconds.  It returns a floating point value -- you know this because you declared start and end as double, but maybe you forgot when you set up your printf specifier.